# Leaflet Loop Snake function on several polyline routes

Tags: javascript, for-loop, animation, leaflet, openstreetmap

I currently have two routes, both I stored in an array. I am trying to sequentially animate the routes (polyline) using the following for loop.

```
var pathmat = [path1, path2];
for (var p = 0; p < 1; p++)
    {
    function snake() {
        pathmat[p].snakeIn();
    }

    pathmat[p].on('snakestart snake snakeend', function(ev){
        console.log(ev.type);
    });
    }
```

It skips directly to animating path2.

Please help.

NOTE: I am an absolute noob in JS.

Comment: which 'snake' library are you using? This here? https://github.com/IvanSanchez/Leaflet.Polyline.SnakeAnim

Comment: Yes I am. I believe @IvanSanchez solved the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be using my very own [Leaflet.SnakeAnim](https://github.com/IvanSanchez/Leaflet.Polyline.SnakeAnim) plugin (you should have mentioned this in your question).

The documentation states that you can use `snakeIn()` on a `L.Polyline` but also on a `L.LayerGroup`, and has examples of that. Also look at the [source code `demo-group.html`](https://github.com/IvanSanchez/Leaflet.Polyline.SnakeAnim/blob/master/demo-group.html), which animates several polylines one after another.

Comment: Yes I have used your snake animation Ivan! 'demo-group.html' gives the the correct result. Do you think I can use the snakingTime value to determine a human date (i.e. 1 second will be one day)? I want to set up a counter of the number of routes to be displayed with a time scale basically